# Is it possible to get the UWP application protocol name at runtime? How?

Tags: uwp, protocols

I'm working on an application that can be activated or launched using a protocol. The protocol is set usually in the appxmanifest file under the declaration tab. What I want to do is to get that protocol name declared in the appxmanifest at run time. Will that be possible? If it is, how can I get that value?

I need to get the application's own protocol so I can tell other apps that this is the protocol to get back to me.

Comment: You are the developer of your app. How could you don't know the protocol you are using? Just show the protocols in your app or your website to tell other apps how to use them!

Comment: And if you mean to get other apps protocol then there is also no such API. Because only the protocol name is useless. To use a protocol, we will need not only the protocol name but also the parameter that can be used in this protocol like what in [Windows Maps app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-maps-app). To let other apps use your protocol successfully, you always need to provide a document to introduce your protocol clearly.

Comment: I don't mean to get protocol of other apps. I understand that I can hardcode my own protocol if I wanted to. But I'm developing a library that can be used by other apps which then communicates via protocol. I wanted to query the apps protocol so that I can send it to another app so that other app will have a way to reply. I know that the app developer can tell my library the protocol but it would be easier if I query it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea - I've not verified yet, but it may work. You can access the your app's AppxManifest.Xml from your app like as following:

```
var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///AppxManifest.xml"); 
StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri); 
using (var ras = await file.OpenReadAsync()) 
{
    // 
}
```

Then, you can read the .xml file and parse the uap:protocol elements. Following code is good example for accessing the .xml and parse with xdocument.

[FeedbackOverlay.xaml.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/rate-my-app/blob/master/RateMyApp/Controls/FeedbackOverlay.xaml.cs)